# How can I align these divs horizontally along the top?

Tags: html, css

Each div contains a list of varying lengths and because I'm using inline-block. I think it's causing it to align along the bottom of the `div` with the most height.

Is there a way I can align these `div` along the top or will I need to give each `div` a unique `id` and `style` them each accordingly?

I made a fiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/Bezzzo/dcqmh2g2/1/

**HTML**

```
<!-- footer -->
<div id="footer" >

    <!--Community div-->
    <div>
      <h3>Community</h3>
      <ul>
          <li>Facebook</li>
          <li>Twitter</li>
          <li>Tumbler</li>
          <li>Google plus</li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <!--Contact  support div-->
    <div>   
      <h3>Contact support</h3>
      <ul>
          <li>support@supportsupport.com.au</li>
      </ul> 
    </div>

    <!--Legal div-->
    <div>   
      <h3>Legal</h3>
      <ul>
          <li>Terms and conditions</li>
          <li>Refund policy</li>
          <li>Privacy Policy</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#footer {
  position: relative;
  width:1033px;
  height: 160px;
  margin:auto;
  border-style:dashed;
}

#footer div {
  display:inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 150px;
  border-style:dashed;
}

#footer ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding:0px;
  margin:0px;
  left:0px;
  right:0px;
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `vertical-align: top;` to your `#footer div`:

```
#footer div {
  border-style: dashed;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 150px;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ghorg12110/dcqmh2g2/3/

Comment: Perfect! I swear i tried that, maybe i placed it in the wrong element.  Thanks

Comment: @user3796133 Please click on the tick next to the correct answer to mark your question as resolved. Thanks.

Comment: I will, though there is a time limit in which i can accept you answer, still 2 minutes to wait  “Patience you must have my young padawan” :-)

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative you can also `display: table;` — Really useful if you want to make use of vertical align. It may not be best for your current situation but it has it's merits.

```
#footer {
  position: relative;
  width:1033px;
  height: 160px;
  margin:auto;
  border-style:dashed;
  /* added */
  display: table;
  /* -- */
}

#footer div {
  /* added */
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
  /* -- */
  position: relative;
  border-style:dashed;
}
```

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/rqqb5ptr/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Just float left all the div and specify them a width but you need to clear div for this. If you want to use inline block then you don't need to specify width and clear left. In this case you can use `vertical-align:top` to `footer div`

JsFiddle : [Using float left](http://jsfiddle.net/dcqmh2g2/4/)
  JsFiddle : [Using inline block](http://jsfiddle.net/dcqmh2g2/6/)

Answer (score 0):

remove `display:inline-block` from `#footer div` and use

```
#footer ul li {  display:inline-block;float: left;}
```

or just

```
#footer ul li {display:inline-block;}
```

in your style